# Why are these two descriptions of property T equivalent.

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

## Definitions.

Let $G$ be a locally compact group.

Given a unitary representation $(H, \sigma)$ of $G$ on a Hilbert space $H$, we say that a vector $v$ of norm $1$ in $H$ is $(K, \varepsilon)$-**invariant**, where $K\subseteq G$ is compact and $\varepsilon>0$, if
$$\| \sigma(x)v-v \|<\varepsilon$$
for all $x\in K$.

We say that a unitary representation $(H, \sigma)$ has **almost invariant vectors** if for each $\varepsilon>0$ and each $K\subseteq G$ compact there exists a $(K, \varepsilon)$-invariant unit vector in $H$.

We say that $G$ has **property $T_1$** if there exist $\varepsilon>0$ and a compact subset $K$ of $G$ such that for every non-trivial irreducible unitary representation $(H,\rho)$ of $G$ no unit vector in $H$ is $(K, \varepsilon)$-invariant.

We say that $G$ has **property $T_2$** if whenever a unitary representation of $G$ has almost invariant vectors, it also has a nonzero invariant vector.

## Question.

On page no. 20 of Lubotzky's *Discrete Groups, Expanding Graphs and Invariant Measures* it is stated that a locally compact group $G$ has property $T_1$ if and only if it has property $T_2$. The author does not provide a proof but gives a few references from where one can read a proof. Two of the references were accessible to me (namely Zimmer's *Ergodic Theory and Semisimple Groups* and Wang's paper *The dual space of semi-simple Lie groups* (Theorem 1.5)).

Neither of the two references seem to address the question (however, it is almost surely because of my lack of knowledge in the subject that I was unable to recognize a solution).

> So in short, can somebody please help me with the proof of the **equivalence of property $T_1$ and property $T_2$.**

PS. Please note that the terms 'property $T_1$ and $T_2$' are not standard and are used only for the purpose of this question.

Comment: There is no way property $T_1$ and property $T_2$ are equivalent. Property $T_1$ implies that there can never be almost invariant vectors, which then makes property $T_2$ vacuously hold. Anyways, I guess a concrete counterexample would be $G = \{e\}$; this has property $T_2$ but not property $T_1$.

Comment: @mathworker21 In the definition of Property $T_1$ we are only talking about *non-trivial* and *irreducible* unitary representations. So the example $G=\{e\}$ does not work since this group only has trivial representations. In the definition of Property $T_2$ we are talking about all unitary representations.